# How to sort a huge file which can't be loaded in memory completely. Is there any algorithm other than merge sort which can be used?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, memory

I have a huge file of numbers/String with delimiter as space. This file can't be loaded in memory as the size is 16 GB and the capacity of RAM is 8 GB.

**I need the logical steps to solve this problem.**

Comment: [External sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)

Comment: The file is split up into chunks that can fit into memory. In this case it appears that sorting an array of pointers to records would be best for sorting each chunk. You could use quick sort, but in the case of sorting an array of pointers, merge sort is usually faster. Once there are a set of sorted chunks on the disk drive, the chunks are then merged, usually up to a 16-way merge, until a single sorted chunk is produced.

Answer (score 0):

If the file consists of records with a unique record ID of some kind and a number of associated fields and you are only needing a subset of fields that fit in memory, then you might load the required fields into memory and sort just those?